# Alacritty Ranger w3m: Images are not showing or disappear after few seconds

Tags: arch-linux, images, terminology, ranger, w3m

I am using Alacritty and ranger. I have also installed `w3m`.
This is part of my `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf`:

```
set preview_images true
set preview_images_method w3m
set w3m_offset 0
```

Most of the time images do not show at all. Just black space. And if they show up they disappear after 2 or 3 seconds.

When I set set `preview_images_method terminology`, it looks like this:

[image]

The versions I use:

- ranger 1.9.3
- Python 3.9.1
- w3m/0.5.3+git20200507

What should I do to be able to preview images in ranger ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 5):

I got it working with [ueberzug](https://github.com/seebye/ueberzug), even inside tmux

```
set preview_images true
set use_preview_script true
set preview_images_method ueberzug
```

and

```
sudo pacman -S ueberzug
```

Also check if your preview script is up to date unless you installed ranger recently.

Comment: Sadly `ueberzug` works only in X11